Logic App deployment fails when connecting to Log Analytics Workspace with managed identity
I want to create a logic app that performs a LogAnalytics query via a bicep deployment. The logic app uses a system assigned identity to connect to the Log Analytics workspace.
When I deploy my bicep file, I receive the following error:
The workflow connection parameter 'azuremonitorlogs' is not valid. The API connection 'azuremonitorlogs' is not configured to support managed identity. (Code: WorkflowManagedIdentityConfigurationInvalid)
My connection is configured as follows:
resource logConnection 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: 'azuremonitorlogs-cdn'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    displayName: 'azuremonitorlogs-cdn'
    customParameterValues: {}
    statuses: [
      {
        status: 'Ready'
      }
    ]
    api: {
      id: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', resourceGroup().location, 'azuremonitorlogs')
      name: 'azuremonitorlogs-cdn'
      displayName: 'Azure Monitor Logs'

      type: 'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis'
    }
    testLinks: []
  }
}

My workflow here:
resource logMonitor 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: 'workflow-cdn-log-monitor'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    state: 'Enabled'
    definition: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      parameters: {
        '$connections': {
          defaultValue: {}
          type: 'Object'
        }
      }
      triggers: {
        ...
      }
      actions: {
        Run_query_and_list_results: {
          runAfter: {}
          type: 'ApiConnection'
          inputs: {
            host: {
              connection: {
                name: '@parameters(\'$connections\')[\'azuremonitorlogs\'][\'connectionId\']'
              }
            }
            method: 'post'
            body: 'AzureDiagnostics | where Category == \'FrontDoorAccessLog\'\n'
            path: '/queryData'
            queries: {
              subscriptions: subscription().subscriptionId
              resourcegroups: resourceGroup().name
              resourcetype: 'Log Analytics Workspace'
              resourcename: 'log-cdn'
              timerange: 'Last 4 hours'
            }
          }
        }
      }
      outputs: {}
    }
    parameters: {
      '$connections': {
        value: {
          azuremonitorlogs: {
            id: subscriptionResourceId(
              'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis',
              resourceGroup().location,
              'azuremonitorlogs'
            )
            connectionId: logConnection.id
            connectionName: 'azuremonitorlogs'
            connectionProperties: {
              authentication: {
                type: 'ManagedServiceIdentity'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


It did not make any difference to assign log analytics read role permissions to the workflow identity. The workflow fails to create. The connection is created (and I manually approved the connection)
I did tried a lot of examples from the internet without any success. Can someone please give me a hint how to to setup the bicep file

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Managed identity auth for logic app is documented here
So your API connection should look like that:
resource logConnection  'Microsoft.Web/connections@2018-07-01-preview' = {
  name: 'azuremonitorlogs-cdn'
  location: location
  kind: 'V1'
  properties: {
    api: {
      id: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', location, 'azuremonitorlogs')
      type: 'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis'
    }
    customParameterValues: {}
    displayName: 'Azure Monitor Logs'
    parameterValueSet: {
      name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
      values: {
        token: {}
      }
    }
  }
}

You would also need to grant Monitoring Reader role to the logic app identity:

log-analytics-role-assignement.bicep file:

param logAnalyticsWorkspaceName string
param roleId string
param principalId string
param principalType string = 'ServicePrincipal'

resource logAnalyticsWorkspace 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2023-09-01' existing = {
  name: logAnalyticsWorkspaceName
}

// Create role assignment
resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(logAnalyticsWorkspace.id, roleId, principalId)
  scope: logAnalyticsWorkspace
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleId)
    principalId: principalId
    principalType: principalType
  }
}


Full working sample - main.bicep file

param location string = resourceGroup().location
param logAnalyticsWorkspaceName string = 'log-cdn'
param logicAppName string = 'workflow-cdn-log-monitor'

// Get a reference to the log analytics workspace
resource logAnalyticsWorkspace 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2023-09-01' existing = {
  name: logAnalyticsWorkspaceName
}

// Create monitor connector for logic app
resource logConnection  'Microsoft.Web/connections@2018-07-01-preview' = {
  name: 'azuremonitorlogs-cdn'
  location: location
  kind: 'V1'
  properties: {
    api: {
      id: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', location, 'azuremonitorlogs')
      type: 'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis'
    }
    customParameterValues: {}
    displayName: 'Azure Monitor Logs'
    parameterValueSet: {
      name: 'managedIdentityAuth'
      values: {
        token: {}
      }
    }
  }
}

// Create the logic app
resource logMonitor 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    state: 'Enabled'
    definition: {
      '$schema': 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      parameters: {
        '$connections': {
          defaultValue: {}
          type: 'Object'
        }
      }
      triggers: {
        When_a_HTTP_request_is_received: {
          type: 'Request'
          kind: 'Http'
        }
      }
      actions: {
        Run_query_and_list_results: {
          runAfter: {}
          type: 'ApiConnection'
          inputs: {
            host: {
              connection: {
                name: '@parameters(\'$connections\')[\'azuremonitorlogs\'][\'connectionId\']'
              }
            }
            method: 'post'
            body: 'AzureDiagnostics | where Category == \'FrontDoorAccessLog\''
            path: '/queryData'
            queries: {
              subscriptions: subscription().subscriptionId
              resourcegroups: resourceGroup().name
              resourcetype: 'Log Analytics Workspace'
              resourcename: logAnalyticsWorkspace.name
              timerange: 'Last 4 hours'
            }
          }
        }
      }
      outputs: {}
    }
    parameters: {
      '$connections': {
        value: {
          azuremonitorlogs: {
            id: subscriptionResourceId(
              'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis',
              resourceGroup().location,
              'azuremonitorlogs'
            )
            connectionId: logConnection.id
            connectionName: 'azuremonitorlogs'
            connectionProperties: {
              authentication: {
                type: 'ManagedServiceIdentity'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Assign monitor reader role to the identity
module keyVaultRoleAssignment './log-analytics-role-assignement.bicep' = {
  name: '${logMonitor.name}-log-analytics-rbac'
  params: {
    logAnalyticsWorkspaceName: logAnalyticsWorkspace.name
    principalId: logMonitor.identity.principalId
    roleId: '43d0d8ad-25c7-4714-9337-8ba259a9fe05' // Monitoring Reader
  }
}

